# Handling duplicates in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to write data from Python to a database in SQL. I use the code below to write contents of one of the tables into SQL, which would then give me the primary keys for the first table, `Table 1`, which I use when writing in data for the next table, `Table 2` as foreign keys of `Table 2` are mapped to `Table 1`. However, I am now writing a function to prevent duplicated data from being written into these tables if I was to run the script again.

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
# Writing data into Table 1
session.add_all([
Table1(name = 'Euro'),
Table1(name = 'Fed'),
Table1(name = 'Aus'),
Table1(name = 'BOE'),
Table1(name = 'Canada')])

session.flush()
session.commit()
session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)    

#Obtaining the primary keys for Table 1
listofindices = []

for row in session.query(Table 1):
    listofindices.append(row.id)
```

So, far the code for handling duplicates is as follows. **However, I am not sure how to obtain the primary keys from `Table 1` and at the same time prevent the duplicated data from being written to it**:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
s = Session()
select_statement = s.execute('select count(*) from Table 1')
result = select_statement.fetchone()
table_exists = result[0] #Does TABLE 1 exist?
if table_exists != 0:
    #DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE TO PREVENT DUPLICATES AS NOW THE TABLE EXISTS
```

Comment: So each time you do session.commit() that's it. It's a sealed deal so be careful where you're writing to. Since you're still deving I would recommend doing s.execute('DELETE from Table 1') before doing your write so you can see what it looks like each time. I'm still looking into your prob*

Comment: @FirebladeDan Thanks. I tried doing what you suggested however I still don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What you're going to want in your tables is create a column called mod_ts or some type of timestamp that will let you know it has recently been written to. E.g. When you do your if table_exists you'd do s.execute('update table where mod_ts <> today'). This will only run it for everyday it is different. That's how you control overwrites